# libGDX interfaces for native android code

Tags: interface, libgdx

I would like to use native android code in my project with help of an interface.

AndroidLauncher:

```
public int getNetworkState() {
    int a;

    ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
        a=1;
    } else {
        a=0;
    }

    return a;
}
```

Core:

```
public interface NetworkState {
    public int getNetworkState();

}
```

How can I get the exact integer value in core project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is solved by doing the following:

Put your platform specific code in a class that implements your interface and have your Game class accept the interface as a parameter in its constructor.

So in your **core project**, you have your Game class;

```
public class GameInstance extends Game {
    private NetworkState networkState;

    public GameInstance(NetworkState networkState) {
        this.networkState = networkState;
    }

    // override methods go below
    ...
}
```

Also, you put your NetworkState interface in the core:

```
public interface NetworkState {
    public int getNetworkState();    
}
```

In your **Android project** you put the implementation;

```
public AndroidNetworkState implements NetworkState {
    public int getNetworkState() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

And then in your AndroidLauncher you create a Game object and pass it the interface implementation:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    NetworkState networkState = new AndroidNetworkState(); // or whatever you called the class
    initialize(new Game(networkState), config);
}
```

And then you can just call the interface method in your core project:

```
...
int networkStateResult = this.networkState.getNetworkState();
...
```

Be sure to provide implementations for other platforms if you support other platforms.

Comment: My class in core would be MainMenu.
MainMenu.NetworkState networkState = new MainMenu.NetworkState(); It says it is abstract, cannot be instantiated.

Comment: Why is it an abstract class?

Comment: What does it mean? It is "normal".... It says also this.networkState cannot resolve.

Comment: Could you include your networkstate class in your post?

Comment: There isn't Networkstate class. What should it contains?

Comment: Can you show me please a "test project", that uses these? This is my last request...

Comment: Like this?

public class NetworkState implements NetworkState.NetworkStateInterface {
    public interface NetworkStateInterface {
        public int getNetworkState();

    }

}

Comment: But there is something wrong with it, because there are a lot of error messages.

Comment: I've extended my answer if it's still giving errors, you'll need to be more descriptive than " a lot of error messages"

Comment: I have a class, MainMenu, I would like to use above integer in this. I have added getNetworkState to AndroidLauncher, after that I have added networkstate interface into Networkstate class.
That is all.